# difference between window.onload and document.ready in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javaScript. Whats the difference between window.onload and document.ready.
I have used both and window.onload seems to fire a bit later than document.ready. Whats the reason?

Answer (score 3):

$(document).ready: executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready

$(window).load: executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

Comment: Thanks for the help. Which one should I generally use?

Comment: If your code is affected by external files like scripts and images, then use window.load else document.ready is fine.